# How and where to define a default domain for my angular resource?

Tags: angularjs, api, cross-domain, angular-resource

Where can and should I define a default url for my angular resource so I don't have to provide an absolute url for every api endpoint that I have?

(The api that I am using is on the same domain but with a a subdomain: http://api.myapp.app/api/v1)

I am quite new to angular and I am trying really hard to get a thorough understanding so I would be ever so thankful if someone could also explain to me the "why" behind the answer.

Comment: Will the api URL always stay the same, or will it never change?

Comment: It might change, but not so often that I will need a build system like suggested below. For me it's just important that I only have to set it in one place within the "app configuration" so to speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using a build system like grunt and your deployment servers will change I would look into [grunt-ng-constant](https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant)

Otherwise you can simply define a constant in your app config like:

```
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .constant("ENV", {
        "ApiEndpoint": "somedomain.com"
    });
```

Then you can pass that around like:

```
angular.module('app').controller('SomeCtrl', function(ENV) {
    // ENV.ApiEndpoint
});
```

Not a true default per se, but at least you won't manually need to type out your base domain in every resource, you'll only need to reference `ENV.ApiEndpoint`

Comment: Thanks Matthew. But this would still imply that for every resource in my api factory I have to prepend this constant? In other words; isn't there a way to let ngResource always use a set domain?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no :(

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to use this in the head of your main html file:
`<base href="/base-url">`

as noted in the angularjs docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) ..scroll down to `Relative Links`

Comment: Thanks, I saw that one but I figured it might interfere with other stuff